# Add image to UiTextView and post it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I want to add smily image in UITextview and also some text and then when i press send button all data from Textview i want to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a container view that will include your `UIImageView` for showing the image and `UITextField` for allowing to enter the text  and **`UIButton`** button to grab the text.

The below is the approach ... which you can use.

```
 [myContainerView addSubview:myImageView];
 [myContainerView addSubview:myTextView];
 [self.view  addSubview:myContainerView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you Try out this one when you [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) rather than the UITextView... i have tried to search a lot for your answer but need some more time to get it done. in the mean while try that out.